# Display the result of query as html in jade template page

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, ckeditor, pug

I have a form where I use ckeditor. It is save in the database as expected.

Here is a part of the *index.js*:

```
mysql.item(content, function(err, result){
        console.log('error: ', err);
        console.log('result: ', result);
        if(result){
            res.render('question', {questions : result, items: result.length});
        }
    });
```

*here is the result of the query:*

```
{ questionId: 2,
questionType: 'True or False',
question: '<p>Yes or No?</p>,
category: 'Chapter 1',
createdBy: 'Me',
createdDate: Wed Mar 19 2014 23:25:39 GMT+0800 (PHT),
modifiedBy: 'Me',
modifiedDate: Wed Mar 19 2014 23:25:39 GMT+0800 (PHT),
courseId: 5 }
```

And then I need to display it into a jade template as a anchor.

*question.jade*

```
h2 All Available Questions
    ul.nav
         - for (var i = 0; i < items; i++)
              li
                  a(href='#') #{i+1}. #{questions[i].question}
```

And it is displayed as:

```
1. <p>Yes or No?</p>
```

But I am expecting to be displayed is:

```
1. Yes or No?
```

What is the best thing to solve this issue? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am following what you want for output, I think you will want to use bang (`!`) instead of the hash(`#`) as your interpolation prefix to prevent it from escaping your HTML embedded in the record result. For example:

```
h2 All Available Questions
    ul.nav
         - for (var i = 0; i < items; i++)
              li
                  a(href='#') #{i+1}. !{questions[i].question}
```

Comment: You are very welcome. The documentation on Jade, as with many node tools, could be better.